# Rails sessions with redis, generating unnecessary session keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, redis

I am having a problem where Redis is gaining a "appSession:*" key at a rate of almost 1 per second. There is no way I have this many users online, there are not even that many users in the database. This cannot be replicated in development or even in production environment on my local instance. It almost seems like it generates a new key on every request (even my OPTION request to get the server status)

I am using these gems:

- rails (= 3.1.6)
- redis-rails (3.1.5)
- redis (3.0.2)
- devise (2.1.2)

Here is my session config

```
    options = if Rails.env == "production"
      {host: 'this.is.a.ip', port: 6379, namespace: 'appSession', :key => '_appSession'}
    else
      {host: 'localhost', port: 6379, namespace: 'appSession', :key => '_appSession'}
    end
    App::Application.config.session_store :redis_store, options
```

If anyone has any light into why it just keeps generating session keys I would be grateful. Right now it is so bad that I have a cron job wipe them out at 1 am just so the server wont die.